# typescript class inheritance and instantiation with object notation

Tags: typescript, inheritance, ecmascript-6

I have a project class which extends an abscract basic class

```
export abstract class Basic {
    _id?: string;
    title?: string;
    titleAbv?: string;
    description?: string;

    startDate?: number | Date;
    endDate?: number | Date;
    duration?: number | Date;
    deadline?: number | Date;

    constructor(newBasic: BasicInterface) {
        this._id = newBasic._id || null;
        this.title = newBasic.title || null;
        this.titleAbv = newBasic.titleAbv || null;
        this.description = newBasic.description || null;

        this.startDate = newBasic.startDate || null;
        this.endDate = newBasic.endDate || null;
        this.duration = newBasic.duration || null;
        this.deadline = newBasic.deadline || null;
    }
}

export interface BasicInterface {
    _id?:string;
    title?: string;
    titleAbv?: string;
    description?: string;

    startDate?: number | Date;
    endDate?: number | Date;
    duration?: number | Date;
    deadline?: number | Date;
}

export class Project extends Basic{

    color?:number;
    clientId?:string;
    clientName?:string;

    constructor(newProject:ProjectInterface){
        super(newProject.basic);
        this.color = newProject.color || 0;
        this.clientId = newProject.clientId || null;
        this.clientName = newProject.clientName || null;
    }
}

export interface ProjectInterface{
    basic:Basic;
    color?:number;
    clientId?:string;
    clientName?:string;
}
```

I'm using the object notation to instantiate so that the order of input doesn't matter. However I need to instantiate with

```
new Project ({basic:{}})
```

if I extend to Project it will look like

```
new ObjectExample ( { project:{basic:{}}})
```

which isn't really nice and I was wondering if there is a way to inherit from classes AND keep the object notation?

Thanks!

Comment: `ProjectInterface extends BasicInterface`?

Comment: wow...that was really easy...thanks :D